# How to get popular Tags using Popular Items' web-part in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app, provider-hosted-app

I want to show **popular tags** used across my site collection. I have tried '**Tag cloud web part**' but it has been retired from SharePoint Online.

To achieve this I have used **'Popular Items**' web part by applying filter on Tag 'Restrict on tag' but I'm not able to see the results.

Are there any workarounds to achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance.